# ¿Cómo hacer un archivo .bat que active un entorno virtual?

Tags: windows, cmd, virtualenv, .bat

estoy tratando de lanzar un archivo .bat con las sentencias mas comunes para ejecutar un entorno virtual:

```
cd C:\<path>\env\Scripts
activate.bat
pause
```

Pero el archivo NO se mantiene abierto, aun con la sentencia "pause" al final. He visto que el inconveniente llega cuando llamo a "activate.bat", entonces quería saber si hay alguna otra forma o estoy cometiendo algún error. Gracias.

Comment: Ejecuta los .bat mediante `call` [https://www.google.com/search?q=llamas+a+un+.bat+desde+otro.bat](https://www.google.com/search?q=llamas+a+un+.bat+desde+otro.bat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar con un bat con los siguientes pasos:

```
@echo off
REM Ubicarnos en la carpeta donde esta el BAT
CD C:\docs\bats
REM Iniciar otro BAT
START activate.bat
echo Presiona Enter para salir
pause>nul
```

Si quieres terminar el BAT deberás presionar la tecla Enter. Otra alterativa sería sustituir la sentencia START por CALL. Espero te sirva.